# Young Adult book featuring old Egyptian gods (set in modern times)

Tags: story-identification

A story identification request about a book I read as a teenager (I would say roughly 25 years ago). As usual for these questions my memory is more than hazy:

- The book played in the modern world (I would say in some US city, although I'm very unsure about this). The main protagonist was a teenage girl. She was on the run from some old Egyptian gods (I believe at least Osiris and Horus?). In the end she receives help from some other god (Amun-Ra?) to overcome them. I remember that the entire story was pretty much an ancient struggle between gods spilling into modern times.
- Style: a "young adult" book in the sense of Hunger Games. Not a children's book (I recall it being borderline frightening as a teenager). Not illustrated (as far as I can remember). The book was a fantasy book only in the sense that gods were in it, otherwise the world was perfectly ordinary. I recall nobody believing the protagonist that she is being hunted by gods.
- This wasn't a romance book. I don't recall love and relationships being a topic in the book at all, and if it was it was sufficiently in the background for me to forget entirely.
- I read the book in German back then, but I suspect that it was translated from English. I read it in paperback form.
- It was a full-length novel, not a short story. It is possible that it was part of a larger series, but in that case it was likely the first part. However, the book did not have a cliff-hanger at the end, making me believe that it was at least not designed as the starting point of a series.
- I suspect that the book is fairly well-known. I got the book as a gift from my aunt, and we lived in a rural town - I would be surprised if she stumbled over a truly obscure fantasy YA novel during gift shopping. Which makes it even more frustrating that I can't seem to figure what the book was.

Comment: Ah, https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17331819-reawakened is far too recent.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yeah, based on the cover text it could be it, but I was well into my thirties in 2015 ;)

Comment: And oh boy, but some people were *really* negative about that book. Maybe with good reason.  :-D I did a quick dive on the author's other books, and the earliest she published was 2011, which apparently was instead about an American solving all of the *Indian* mythology problems with an improbably handsome reincarnated prince.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I also don't recall any sort of love life being in the book, so that (apparently terrible) piece of literature certainly wasn't it. The way I recall it the protagonist spent a fair bit of time scared, and I don't recall any love interest at all.

Comment: Rick Riordan's *Kane Chronicles* is also too recent (2010) ... https://rickriordan.com/book/the-red-pyramid/

Comment: It reminds me of Enki Bilal's 2004 film [Immortal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immortal_%282004_film%29), based on his graphic novel [La Foire aux Immortels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Foire_aux_immortels).